# How to subtract two columns which are inside brackets

Tags: sql, sas, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

### Below is the SAS code which I need to convert into an SQL query:

```
data table2 (keep = Date id Differential);
   set table1 
   Differential = ReturnsGross-ReturnsNet;
   where ((ReturnsGross ^=. and ReturnsNet ^=.) as Differential 
run;
```

### Corresponding SQL code: I have imported the input table(table1) in dataiku platform

```
select Date, id,
CASE WHEN(ReturnsGross !='' AND ReturnsNet !='')
THEN (CAST(ReturnsGross AS INT)-CAST(ReturnsNet AS INT)) END AS Differential
FROM table1
```

[ReturnsGross, ReturnsNet are string columns of numeric values inside brackets]

Here I am getting the Error as **Numeric value (5.25%) is not recognized**

The input dataset value is like below:
[image]

Comment: % isn't a number thus the data type conversion error.  You'd need to replace it with '' prior to conversion and divide your columns by 100 (assuming % is on EVERY row)

Comment: It sounds like you have character variables and you are trying to use them as if they were numeric variables. Show examples of the values that are in the variables that are character.  Also show what actual number those strings should represent.  There is probably a SAS informat that can convert the strings into numbers, but we need to see examples to be able suggest which informat to use.

Comment: That isn't valid SAS code.

Answer (score 1):

so a series of steps we can transform the text input into correct numbers

```
SELECT 
    column1 as id
    ,column2 as returns_gross_txt
    ,column3 as returns_net_txt
    ,trim(returns_gross_txt, '()% ') as t_returns_gross
    ,trim(returns_net_txt, '()% ') as t_returns_net
    ,try_to_double(t_returns_gross)/100 as returns_gross
    ,try_to_double(t_returns_net)/100 as returns_net
FROM VALUES 
(1, '( 0.00%)', '( 0.22%)'),
(1, '( 0.00%)', '( 0.52%)'),
(1, '( 0.00%)', '( -0.82%)')
;
```

gives:

| ID | RETURNS_GROSS_TXT | RETURNS_NET_TXT | T_RETURNS_GROSS | T_RETURNS_NET | RETURNS_GROSS | RETURNS_NET |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ( 0.00%) | ( 0.22%) | 0 | 0.22 | 0 | 0.0022 |
| 1 | ( 0.00%) | ( 0.52%) | 0 | 0.52 | 0 | 0.0052 |
| 1 | ( 0.00%) | ( -0.82%) | 0 | -0.82 | 0 | -0.0082 |

and then we can compact that up a little

```
SELECT 
    column1 as id
    ,try_to_double(trim(column2, '()% '))/100 as returns_gross
    ,try_to_double(trim(column3, '()% '))/100 as returns_net
FROM VALUES 
(1, '( 0.00%)', '( 0.22%)'),
(1, '( 0.00%)', '( 0.52%)'),
(1, '( 0.00%)', '( -0.82%)')
;
```

| ID | RETURNS_GROSS | RETURNS_NET |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 0.0022 |
| 1 | 0 | 0.0052 |
| 1 | 0 | -0.0082 |

once you have you values as numbers, you can now do subtraction:

```
SELECT 
    column1 as id
    ,try_to_double(trim(column2, '()% '))/100 as returns_gross
    ,try_to_double(trim(column3, '()% '))/100 as returns_net
    ,returns_gross - returns_net as Differential
FROM VALUES 
(1, '( 1.00%)', '( 0.22%)'),
(2, '( 2.00%)', '( 0.52%)'),
(3, '( 3.00%)', '( -0.82%)')
;
```

giving:

| ID | RETURNS_GROSS | RETURNS_NET | DIFFERENTIAL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.01 | 0.0022 | 0.0078 |
| 2 | 0.02 | 0.0052 | 0.0148 |
| 3 | 0.03 | -0.0082 | 0.0382 |

Comment: Love it.  Nice solid complete solution based on data provided.!

Answer (score 0):

Hi use REPLACE in the column having the % sign and then do the mathematical operation, it may work

```
select replace('1.2345%','%') ;
```